# eval'd code problem in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal

When i login to my drupal page. It's showing the following error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /document_root/sites/all/modules/rules/rules/modules/php.rules.inc(107) :
```

eval()'d code on line 1

When i just figure out to the particular page there is no problem in that function . Below is the function where the error marked..

```
function rules_php_eval_return($code, $arguments = array()) {
  extract($arguments);
  return eval($code);
}
```

Could any one can suggest me what's the problem may be!! It's drupal 6.x version.

Comment: I don't know Drupal: what's supposed to pass throught that function? when is it used? The script points there because the error is happening there, if the function is a core function it's surely right, it's the input which has something wrong. You should look into that.

Comment: The notable Point is the problem is not coming when the file was in my local server but when it moved to the online server it's rising this problem..

Comment: You probably are using custom PHP within one of your rules and there is an error somewhere in there.  Check your triggered rules.  Try replacing the custom PHP with simple statements such as `return TRUE` if checking a value or use `print/echo` if outputting a value

Comment: Now everything is changed. When the first time i accessed the page it's shows the above format of error. But now it's showing some other kind of error in the same first line. I try to echo the above $code value but no use. Still it's showing the error not printing the value what i tried.

Comment: The echo is worked now.. It's printing the following value "return 1"..

Comment: Don't forget that in html the "<?php" won't show up in your echo...... html_entities is needed here

Comment: Now the site is working finely as like that local machine. In the production mode i forgot to mention the display_error off.

Answer (score 2):

I came accross an error like this when I pasted a PHP code snippet from the Drupal site into a block to show submenus. These submenus were detected and assigned in a foreach loop, but since there weren't any submenus, the menu variable remained unassigned and thus undeclared as well.

My obvious solution was to assign an empty string to the menu variable before the foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know drupal, but i think that $code contains something like :

```
$code = '<?php $someCode;';
eval($code);
//Produces : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in file(1) : eval()'d code on line 1
```

The error is telling you that $code contains a parse error (maybe the phptag)

You an echo $code to check what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

eval'd usually comes when bad custom php codes embeded in site using php module(php filter)
If you can access site in anyway, go to Triggered Rules and Rule Sets page and find if any rule is firing a custom php code.
It's idiot's style to put php codes in Rules. Either you should create a module or use Rules itself :)

If you can't access the site, go to /modules folder and move the "php" folder somewhere else. Then you will be able to access site. Quickly remove buggy code and replace the folder.
Then, start debugging it.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same problem trying to process data returned from an HTTP request.  I was using simplexml_load_string, but the HTTP response was an error, so the data was not formatted as XML, thus causing simplexml to error (propogate up).  My message was the same as yours, "error in file on line X; eval'd() code on line X".  So, it may not necessarily be an error within your code, or even the eval'd code.

While it looks like you don't have the following issue, it is something to keep in mind as well.  When declaring variables within the eval'd code they will scope the same as if inline in the file.  Similarly, variables preceding the eval'd code are available within it, and may cause collisions, or inadvertent re-assigning (eg. $i in nested loops).